# nodester init app error

Tags: node.js

When i try init app on nodester (from win) i get error above. I think this problem was started when  nodester reached 1.0 status.

```
(1) Setup a new app from scratch?
(2) You just want to setup your existent app?
note: if you choose 2 be sure that you are into app's dir
(1) 1
nodester info initializing git repo for <folder> into folder <folder>
nodester warn this will take a second or two
nodester info cloning your new app in <folder>
nodester ERROR { [Error: Command failed: ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null}
nodester not ok!
```

Folder and my files on disc is successfully created. Creating, starting and stoping app working fine. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing has change in that part, which is weird. What I can suggest you is to run that command in the git-shell. On windows the `git` command usually is not in the PATH. Maybe that can be the problem. Also you can join us on irc.nodester.com or #nodester in freenode. So we can help you a little bit more.